# Can I run stackblitz on my android phone?

Tags: android, angular, components, stackblitz

I run stackblitz site on my android phone, and create an angular project. But when I want to create a new component, I don't see any place for typing the name of the component and therefore I can't create the component.
When I touch the "angular generator", then touch "component" choice, the keyboard appears but there isn't any place for typing the name of the component.

[Screenshot from stackblitz on my android phon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTIIh.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgyqa.jpg)

Comment: when add a component rotate to landscape. You see that you're write the name of the component (you can also simply type and give ENTER)

Comment: Thanks a lot Eliseo, it's worked, but I don't have ENTER key on my keyboard, I hold GO key instead of ENTER, and it worked correctly. So is there any way to add ENTER key to my Samsung keyboard?

Comment: it's true, sorry, there are no ENTER (in Spanish is "Ir", I imagine in English is "Go")